# Min valule in dict

Tags: python

my function return a dict `{1: 10.0, 2: 9.0, 3: 2.5}`

so i did try `a = {1: 10.0, 2: 9.0, 3: 2.5}`

```
for i in a.keys()
    prin min(i)
```

but getting

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

can someone explain me how can I get a value that is minimal in this dict?

Comment: `print(min(a.values()))` ?

Comment: The minimum key or the minimum value?

Comment: What does [**`min`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) expect as a parameter?

Comment: Stop to thinking about what the code is doing. You are iterating over the keys, so `i` will have a starting value of, say, `1`. Then, you are doing `min(i)` which translates to `min(1)`. What do you expect `min(1)` to return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this -

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Because `min` expects an iterable. Look at the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min)

But `for i in a.keys()` gives you `int` and you can not iterate over an `int` object. Pass a list like -

```
min(a) or min(a.values()) # depending on your requirement
```

Comment: @PeterWood, right, edited

Answer (score 2):

One of these should do it

```
def min_value(d):
    return min(d.values())

def min_key(d):
    return min(d)

def key_of_min_value(d):
    return min(d.items(), key=lambda pair: pair[1])[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you are trying to get the min value of an int.

In fact in your code you're doing:

```
for 1 in a:
    print min(1)
```

you must insert the dictionary and not its value in the `min` function (which takes an iterable argument)

so you can do:

```
>>> a = {1: 10.0, 2: 9.0, 3: 2.5}
>>> min(a)
1
```

But in fact you pass the keys arguments.

If you want the `min` value of the dict values, you should do:

```
>>> a = {1: 10.0, 2: 9.0, 3: 2.5}
>>> min(a.values())
2.5
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the key for the minimum value, `min` takes a `key` function which is used for the comparison. You can pass a lambda which will compare values instead of keys:

```
key_for_minimum_value = min(key for key, value in a.items(),
                            key=lambda (key, value): value)
```

Or, more tersely, and using a dictionary lookup instead (which may be slightly less efficient):

```
key_for_minimum_value = min(a, key=a.get)
```